# Stream Analytics possible output path prefix for Data Lake Store

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

Is there any way to set an output path prefix in Stream Analytics job that store data to Data Lake Store to store it into separate files (that dependent on device id) for example data/2017/5/3/device1.csv , data/2017/5/3/device2.csv ... Or what is the best way to do this after stream analytics store data to one file ? 
My input file is iot hub.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to set an output path prefix in Stream Analytics job that store data to Data Lake Store to store it into separate files (that dependent on device id) for example data/2017/5/3/device1.csv , data/2017/5/3/device2.csv.

According to the **[document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-data-lake-output)**, base on my understanding, we could set an output path prefix with {date}/{time} and there is no requirement that the variables must be used.

[image]

It seems that it is not supported to set an output path with dynamic device id.
If it is possible to create multiple Stream Analytics jobs, we could create Stream Analytics job and add output with the static device id as path prefix.